# Lazy Query graphql response data is not accessible inside react after executing the query

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I need to call a query when Download button is pressed and then handle the response.I only need to execute the query when download button is pressed and not when the react component loads. Hence I used 'useLazyQuery' option from graphql.

I need something like this:

```
const [downloadAllRecipients,{ loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY,
    {
      variables: {
        campaignId: props.campaignId,
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
    },
  );

//This is the download button onPress event handler.
const downloadDataButton = async () => {
  const res = await downloadAllRecipients({ variables: { campaignID: props.campaignId }})
  console.log(res) // handle response
}
//Output:-
//undefined
```

When executing the above query, **res** is undefined. However, the graphql query was seen in the network layer. I have a react frontend and am not able to access the data returned by the query.Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will get the data in `onCompleted` event.

So your code should look like following,

```
const [downloadAllRecipients,{ loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY,
    {
      variables: {
        campaignId: props.campaignId,
      },
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
     onCompleted: res => { setRes(res); console.log(res);}
    },
  );
```